# Poisson Probability Question -Please help

Tags: poisson-distribution

Can you please help me on this question
The number of fishes caught by a fisherman is Poisson with an average of $6$ fishes per hour, assume he caught $8$ fishes in the last hour, what is the probability of no fish was caught in the first $10$ minutes?
Thanks much for your help!

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know the memorylessness property of the Poisson process?

Comment: Yes, here is what I did: P(N(50))=8, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

First we need to find the mean number of fishes caught in $10$ minutes. We can find this by converting the mean from hour to minutes: $\mu= \dfrac{6 \text{ fishes}}{1\text{hr}}\times \dfrac{1\text{ hr}}{6 \text{ (10-minutes)}}= \dfrac{1 \text{ fish}}{10 \text{ minutes}}= 1$. Thus we have: $P(x = k) = \dfrac{\mu^k\cdot e^{-\mu}}{k!}$. Plug $k = 0, \mu = 1$ into the formula we have: $P(x = 0) = e^{-1}= 0.368$

Comment: thank you for your help. This makes sense for 6 fishes per hour. However, he caught 8 fishes in last hour and the ask was what the probability was for him not to catch any in the first 10 minutes.  So I thought the solution should be the memorylessness property, to calculate what the property is for him to caught 8 fishes in the last 50 minutes.

Comment: Good concern. Do you have the answer for this question from your teacher? I want to know about it and we can adjust our answer to suit it. My answer is "preliminary" meaning it is not finalized yet unless it IS the correct answer.

Comment: No, don't know what the correct answer is. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** One of the properties* of the Poisson distribution is that under the condition that $n$ events have occurred in the the interval $(0,t)$, the times at which the events occurred are distributed independently and uniformly in $(0,t)$.

So suppose $x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots , x_8$ are chosen independently and uniformly in $(0,1)$.  What is the probability that none of them fall in the interval $(0, 1/6)$?

* Reference: Theorem 5.2, *Introduction to Probability Models, 9th Edition* by Sheldon M. Ross.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the event that no fish was caught in the first 10 minutes of the hour, and $B$ be the event that 8 fish were caught in the hour.

Since the fish are caught at a rate of 6 per hour on average (equivalently 1 per 10 minutes or 5 per 50 minutes), using Bayes' theorem yields:

$$\mathbb{P}(A|B)
= \mathbb{P}(B|A) \cdot \frac{\mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}
= \frac{5^8}{8!}e^{-5} \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{0!}e^{-1}}{\frac{6^8}{8!}e^{-6}}
= \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^8
= 0.232568
$$

because $\mathbb{P}(B|A)$ corresponds to the probability of catching 8 fish in 50 minutes. Note that the solution of $(5/6)^8$ can be arrived at elegantly using [awkward's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3609565/458055).